# Why aren't my custom post type posts showing up?

Tags: wordpress, themes, custom-post-type, posts

I created a custom post type - Press - using the following code in functions.php:

```
// Press Custom Post Type //

function press_custom_init() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Press', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Press', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'press'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Press Item'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Item'),
        'new_item' => __('New Press Item'),
        'view_item' => __('View Press Item'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Press'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug','pages'),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','excerpt',)
      );

    register_post_type( 'press' , $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'press_custom_init' );
```

I have added items of that post type and added a menu item to my nav bar but when I click on the link, I get a 'no posts found' message.

You can see it here: http://s13.mynewsitereview.com//press

Please help!

Comment: Did you refresh the permalink settings?

Answer (score 10):

**Just visit** the Permalinks page `http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` in the WP-admin to fix this issue.

**Why?**

After creating any addons (post-type, taxonomies, ect.) in WordPress, WordPress needs to update/create a new set of **rewrite rules** (assuming you are using pretty permalinks). All you need to do is visit the permalinks page in your backend so that you can **generate new rules** for your new post type, ect. The technical term is *Flushing Rewrite Rules* (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules)